# How to build URL from template to the admin pages

Tags: django, url, admin

Once deployed onto a production server my django app URLs are like
http://example.com/myapp/Widget/10

I'd like to put a link to the admin forms in my pages.  Not sure
the correct way to put an

```
<a href="?">Go to admin</a>
```

in my templates
so that I can correctly get from a URL like the above for widgets to the admin page which would be http://example.com/myapp/admin

I can't do something like

```
<a href="/admin">
```

because this only works on the dev server but not in production.  Is there a way to use the syntax like {% url admin %} to get to the admin page correctly?  Not sure how to code the urlpattern if I add something like

```
url(r'^admin$', ?, name='admin')
```

in my urls.py

Comment: Do `{% url 'admin:index' %}` or other URL patterns from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls work?

Comment: yes that works.  I thought I needed to define a urlpattern in my urls.py so that I could use stuff like {% url 'adminXXX' %} in my templates.   I guess these are predefined?